# Change Fragment in a tabbed Activity with a Button

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm developing an application in which I have to implement a function that allows to me to change a Fragment with a Button instead of crawling the site on the screen.

**Tutorial.java**

```
public class Tutorial extends AppCompatActivity {
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tutorial_main);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

**PlaceholderFragment.java**

```
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {}

        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tutorial, container, false);

            Button next = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.next);
            Button previous = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.previous);
            RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.relative_tutorial);

            switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)){

                 case 1:
                     rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.one);
                     previous.setText("ESCI");

                     previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                         public void onClick(View v) {
                             getActivity().finish();
                         }
                     });

                     next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                         public void onClick(View v) {

                         }
                     });

                 break;

                 case 2:
                     rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.two);

                     next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                         public void onClick(View v) {

                         }
                     });
                 break;

                 case 3:
                     rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.three);
                     next.setText("HOME");

                     next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                         public void onClick(View v) {
                         getActivity().finish();
                         Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                         startActivity(intent);
                         }
                     });
                 break;
             }
            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

**SectionsPagerAdapter.java**

```
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "SECTION 1";
                case 1:
                    return "SECTION 2";
                case 2:
                    return "SECTION 3";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

How I can switch "page" by clicking my Button, instead of crawling the site on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you display another fragment. So, just put this code inside your buttons onclick method.

**Example:**

```
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, new Fragment_1(), "frag1");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: I don't want "another" fragment, I hate to switch to "position +1"